# Change boolean parameter depending on html checkbox

Tags: html, typescript

I have a boolean value called isPublic and i wanna set it to true or false depending on if the user checked the check box or not, how can i do that?

Here is the parameter :

isPublic : boolean = false;

And here is the checkbox :

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="newGalleryIsPublic">Publique
```

So if the check box is checked, I wanna set the isPublic to true and if not, make it false.

Haven't really found anything on that so if some can help it would be great!

Comment: with or without `<form>` element ?

Comment: without form element. Sorry forgot to add that.

Comment: can i just add [(ngModel)]="isPublic" and it'll detect the value or no?

Answer (score 0):

something like that ?

```js
const chkBox = document.querySelector('[name="newGalleryIsPublic"]');

var isPublic = chkBox.checked;
 

chkBox.addEventListener('change', evt =>
  {
  isPublic = chkBox.checked;
  console.clear();
  console.log(isPublic);
  });
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="newGalleryIsPublic"> Publique
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector("input");
var isChecked;
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
     isChecked = true
    
  } else {
    isChecked = false
  }
  console.log(isChecked)
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="newGalleryIsPublic">Publique
```

Comment: I could try that but I wonder, if I just added to the input [(ngModel)]="isPublic", would it actually detect the input and change my value?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  What is [(ngModel)] = "isPublic" ?